# SpringBoot Actuator Maintain State

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I'm pushing custom metrics to Prometheus using micrometer. So, prometheus scrapes `/actuator/prometheus` and stores data. But the problem is, when I redeploy my applications, all the values are resetting to 0.

Ex: I'm pushing the request count to prometheus. The request count reached to 5. For some reason I deployed a newer version of my SpringBoot application. No request count will start from 0 as actuator is in-memory. So, my prometheus graph is falling down to 0 and starting again.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Storage of metrics is not done inside Spring App but stored inside your prometheus storage.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. To cite from ["Prometheus Counters and how to deal with them"](https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/prometheus-counters/):

> The current value of a Counter doesn't matter. What matters is, how it increases over time.

So, to fix your issue, fix your query by applying [`rate()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate) or [`increase()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase).